# What is the meaning of exterior here and how to find the solution?

Tags: circles, conic-sections, area

Find the area of the circle $x^2+y^2=16$ which is exterior to the parabola $y^2=6x$ using definite integral.

My attempt-

I have solved two to find intersection point $(2,\sqrt{12})$.

But when its come to exterior area. I have no clue. Please help me.

Comment: Did you try drawing the parabola and circle?

Comment: @AdamHughes The axis of the parabola is horizontal hence "below the parabola" does not apply.

Comment: With anything convex I would assume they mean the area of the region on the "convex side" of it, but if you have doubts I would simply ask the person who posed the problem to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Area bounded by two regions,

= $\int_0^2 \sqrt{6x} \,dx + \int_2^4 \sqrt{16-x^2}\,dx$

Then multiply this area with 2 as it is symmetric.

Area of circle = $πr^2$

= $π(4)^2$

= 16π

**Required exterior area = Area of circle - Area bounded by two regions.**

Answer (score 1):

A non degenerated parabola divides the plane in two regions. Only one of them is convex. The convex region is often called the "interior" of the parabola.

[image]

Since the area has the $X$ axis as a symmetry axis, you can find the area above and multiply it by $2$.

This part can be divided in two: a quarter of circle (at left) whose area can be found with the known formula $\pi r^2$, or if you are not allowed to use this kind of formulas, with the integral
$$\int_{-4}^0f(x)dx$$
and the "curved triangle" at right, that is between the circle and the parabola, which can be found with the integral
$$\int_0^2(f(x)-g(x))dx$$

where $f$ is the function that describes the circle and $g$ is that of the parabola.

Note that you must solve the respective equations for $y$ in order to find appropiate expressions for $f$ and $g$.

Comment: but what is the answer and how to find?

Comment: Can you tell me how to find area bounded by parabola and circle using integral then I find remaining area by subtracting it from the area of a circle.

Answer (score 0):

The exterior of a conic is the set of points from where you can draw tangents to it (including asymptotes for the hyperbola).

[image]

The drawing should make it clear what region you're concerned with. Of course you can just compute the area delimited by the arc $OA$, the arc $AB$ and the segment $OB$ in the drawing below and then subtract twice it from the are of the circle.

[image]

Comment: But how to integrate this?

Comment: @JohnSr $\displaystyle\int_0^2\sqrt{6x}\,dx+\int_2^4\sqrt{16-x^2}\,dx$